# Handling leap seconds on sub second precision UTC time arithmetic

Tags: datetime, c++11, time, signal-processing, real-time

I'm doing a real time signal processing:

My inputs are samples tagged with timestamps.
My outputs are estimations tagged with timestamps in **UTC**

I need to compensate for processing delay, so at sample `N` I'll output the estimations of sample `N-K`, `K` being my processing delay.

The time compensation must be leap second aware. ie, with a delay of `10ms`:

```
INPUT  TS = 20150701T000000.000000 
OUTPUT TS = 20150630T235960.990000
```

I thought of `struct tm` as timestamps, making use of the 61st second.

But I wasn't able to find ( `struct tm` <-> *TAI* ) translation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [D. J. Bernstein's libtai](https://cr.yp.to/libtai/taia.html) and *external TAI64 format* values for your timestamps.

Answer (score -1):

[Howard Hinnant's timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) (free, open-source, cross-platform, C++11) will handle this:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{"20150701T000000.000000"};
    utc_time<microseconds> ts;
    in >> parse("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", ts);
    ts -= 10ms;
    std::cout << format("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", ts) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
20150630T235960.990000
```

`utc_time<microseconds>` is a microsecond-precision time stamp that is leap-second aware.  One can do arithmetic on it, format it and parse it.  It depends on the [IANA timezone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) for its source of leap second information.  This library can be configured to automatically download this information, or it can be downloaded manually.  The [documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) has full installation instructions for linux, macOS, and Windows.  Even iOS and Android have support.  The library is portable from C++11 and forward.

This library has also been voted into the draft C++20 specification, and has been documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock).  So when the time comes, you will be able to get this functionality from your C++ vendor instead of from [this timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).